# Get selected value from dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the selected value from the dropdown, but have no luck.

```
<select class="form-control" name="cars" onchange="getAvailableCars();">
   <?php getCars() ?>
</select>
```

getCars() function retrieves all available cars from the database, and they show in the dropdown menu.

Here is function getCars()

```
function getCars(){
    $link = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "cars");
    $link->set_charset("utf8");

    $sql=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT CarID, CarCode, CarName FROM cars a WHERE CarAvailable = 1");

    echo '<option value="">Select </option>';
    while($record=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo '<option value= "' .$record['CarID']. '">' . $record['CarCode'] ."-|-". $record['CarName'] .' </option><br/>';
    }
}
```

Then I created JS function which will get selected Card ID from the select menu.

```
<script>
    function getAvailableCars() {

        var car = document.getElementById("cars");
        var selectedCar= car.options[car.selectedIndex].value;

        console.log(selectedCar);
        /*
        var arr = {artikal:selectedCar};
        $.ajax({ url: 'available-cars.php?a=1',
            data: arr,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(output) {
                document.getElementById("cars").value = output;
            }
        });
        */
    }
</script>
```

Console displays issue:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'options')
```

Also, I have tried with Jquery, but I got in console undefined.

```
var cars = $("#cars:selected").val();
```

I was following link below, any other too but for some reasons, I cannot get the selected value:
[get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: You added attribute `name` to tag `select` you should replace with `id` attribute or add it: `<select class="form-control" name="cars" id="cars" onchange="getAvailableCars();">

Comment: @Raffaele that is correct. Thanks a lot, not sure how I missed this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is your car variable is not called right.

```
var car = document.getElementById("cars");
```

but your form have class = "form-control" and name = "cars" and dont have any id

```
<select class="form-control" name="cars" onchange="getAvailableCars();">
```

You may change car into

```
var car = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control");
// or
var car = document.querySelector(".form-control");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  Select your favorite fruit:
  <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
  </select>
</form>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When a user selects an option from the dropdown menu, the JavaScript function `myFunction()` is triggered, and the selected value is displayed in a paragraph element with the id "demo". This allows users to select their favorite fruit from the list of options.

**Here's a breakdown of how the code works:**

1. The HTML `<form>` tag is used to create a form element.
2. Inside the form, there's a `<select>` element with the id "mySelect". This is a dropdown menu containing several `<option>` elements.
3. Each `<option>` element represents a fruit (Apple, Orange, Pineapple, Banana) and has a `value` attribute associated with it.
4. The `onchange` attribute in the `<select>` element specifies that the `myFunction()` JavaScript function should be called whenever the user changes the selected option.
5. The JavaScript function `myFunction()` is defined within a `<script>` tag. It retrieves the selected value from the dropdown using `document.getElementById("mySelect").value` and then updates the innerHTML of the paragraph element with the id "demo" to display the selected value.

This code allows users to interact with the dropdown menu, select a fruit, and see the selected fruit's name displayed below the dropdown menu.